# Разделить строку регулярным выражением и сохранить скобки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, которую нужно разбить методом split() на токены. Например такая: **"{abcdefg}"**. При этом я должен получит следующие токены: **"{", "abcdefg", "}"**. Вопрос: как мне сохранить скобки?

Comment: А как вы разбиваете сейчас? Почему у вас скобки пропадают?

Comment: Да я вот даже и не знаю как разбить так, чтобы они не пропали...

Comment: Вопрос: как вы НЕ сохраняете скобки?

Answer (score 0):

Не регулярки, но раз я код написал, не пропадать же добру

```
public static ArrayList<String> splitMe(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    if (input == null || input.length() == 0)
        return ret;

    int ind = 0;

    while (ind < input.length()) {
        while (ind < input.length() && (input.charAt(ind) == '{' || input.charAt(ind) == '}')) {
            ret.add(new String(new char[] { input.charAt(ind) }));
            ind++;
        }

        int start = ind;
        while (ind < input.length() && (input.charAt(ind) != '{' && input.charAt(ind) != '}'))
            ind++;
        if (start < input.length())
            ret.add(input.substring(start, ind));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
System.out.println(splitMe("qqq{111}{2222}{}{}{}333"));
```

Результат

```
[qqq, {, 111, }, {, 2222, }, {, }, {, }, {, }, 333]
```